# Send binary message using Net::Stomp::Client

Tags: perl, activemq-classic, stomp, messagebroker

I need to send a binary message to Message Broker using the perl library `Net::Stomp::Client`. But whenever I send a message using the `send` or `send_with_receipt` methods, the message is received as a Text message.
I'm using `ActiveMQ` in my server, and when I call consume, the received message is of type `TextMessage`. I need it to be of type `BytesMessage`.

**Update:**

I see in this [link](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) that setting the content-length header will set the type to Bytes message... But I didn't find any example using Net::Stomp::Perl... If anyone can provide an example it would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `bytes_message => 1` to the `send()` method
In newer versions you need to use stomp 1.1 or greater (default is 1.0) (pass `version` or `accept_version` to the stomp client constructor) and higher and set the `content-type`